# Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api/login to http://localhost:3000/ (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to test this tool https://github.com/feekosta/JSONSchemaDiscovery, I installed and ran it, but I can't log in or register a new access.

I'm getting this as an error:

```
[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api/login to http://localhost:3000/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors).
```

have tried using 127.0.0.1 and [::1] inplace of localhost, but didn't work.

```
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I also tried using other versions of NodeJS (e.g, 14, 16 e 18).